# can't connect to database, can't insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem to insert email, password and name to mySQL database.
I prepared a seperated class to connect my database. But when I put my name, email and password in my form (this is in an other php file) then theire is nothing in my database.
Here you can find my code. I already tried the insert statement in my database and that worked.

```
<?php
include_once("classes/User.class.php");
include_once("Tweet.php");

class Db
{
  private $m_sHost="localhost";
  private $m_sUser="root";
  private $m_sPassword="";
  private $m_sDatabase="phples";
  public $conn;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->conn=new mysqli($this->m_sHost,$this->m_sUser,$this->m_sPassword,$this->m_sDatabase);
    if(isset($m_bVerzend)) {
      if(!$conn->connect_errno) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 'tbltweet' ('Name', 'Email', 'Password') VALUES ('$m_sName', '$m_sEmail', '$m_sPassword');";
        $conn->query($sql);
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? If so please edit your post to include them. Thank you.

Comment: you have to escape variables that are insterted in database queries!!11

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor you are using a lot of variables that are not set in the scope of the function:

```
    if(isset($m_bVerzend)){
    if(!$conn->connect_errno)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 'tbltweet' ('Name', 'Email', 'Password') VALUES ('$m_sName', '$m_sEmail', '$m_sPassword');";
        $conn->query($sql);}
    }
```

All variables like `$m_bVerzend`, `$m_sName`, etc. are simply undefined.

There is more information about variable scope available in the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

By the way, you should also use prepared statements with bound variables instead of dumping your variables in your sql statement to prevent sql injection problems.

Answer (score 0):

variables $m_bVerzend, $m_sName, $m_sEmail and $m_sPassword are do not exist within the function. As standard, PHP's variables are considered local scope unless otherwise specified.

I would send the values as parameters of the constructor, or just use the constructor to instantiate the connection and then use a different procedure to receive the parameters, prepare the SQL statement and execute the query.